# Error when using split function: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: javascript

what is wrong in this code? Somebody could help me?

```js
export class Base64 {

    static getMimeType(urlBase64){

        let regex = /^data:(.+);base64,(.*)$/;
        let result = urlBase64.match(regex);
        return result[1];

    }

    static toFile(urlBase64){

        let mimeType = Base64.getMimeType(urlBase64);
        let ext = mimeType.split('/')[1];
        let filename = `file${Date.now()}.${ext}`;

        return fetch(urlBase64)
            .then(res => { return res.arrayBuffer(); })
            .then(buf => { return new File([buf], filename, { type: mimeType }); });

    }

}
```

this error appears: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: You have two attempts at reading index `1` from something. Which one is causing the error?

Comment: let mimeType = Base64.getMimeType(urlBase64); are you trying to call getMimeType here? I think it should be this.getMimeType instead.